# Windows Admin can not change the time

Tags: security, windows-xp

On my work laptop I have a local admin account that is in both the administrator group and the backup operators group.  This the account cannot install windows updates or change the time.  I've asked my help desk but they are baffled.

Any ideas?

WinXP pro.
joined to domain but logon locally because I'm remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talk to the folks who administer your group policies. Both of those can be locked down via GPOs.

Answer (score 0):

The group policy setting is Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Locale Services > Disallow user override of locale settings